# How execute python3 script remotely via cURL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, wget

I have this file here

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Goal : Remove file base on input match
# Run  : curl 45.55.88.57/code/fileModifier.py  | python3


import os
import sys

rootdir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
print(rootdir)




#Give string to remove from folder names. Ensure that removing a string doens't make the folder name empty. It wont work
removeStringFromFolderName = input('Remove this from folder names :')
while removeStringFromFolderName == '':
    print('Empty string not allowed')
    removeStringFromFolderName = input('Remove this file if contain : ')

count = 0
subdir = [x for x in os.walk(rootdir)]
toRemove = []
for chunk in subdir:
    folders = chunk[1]
    if len(folders) > 0:
        for aDir in folders:
            if removeStringFromFolderName in aDir:
                toRemove.append((chunk[0], aDir))


toRemove.reverse()

for folders in toRemove:
    oldPath = (os.path.join(folders[0], folders[1]))
    newPath = (os.path.join(folders[0], folders[1].replace(removeStringFromFolderName,'')))
    os.rename(oldPath, newPath)
    count +=1

subdir = [x for x in os.walk(rootdir)]
for chunk in subdir:
    folders = chunk[1]
    if len(folders) > 0:
        for aDir in folders:
            if removeStringFromFolderName in aDir:
                print(os.path.join(chunk[0], aDir))
                oldPath = (os.path.join(chunk[0], aDir))
                newPath = (os.path.join(chunk[0], aDir.replace(removeStringFromFolderName,'')))
                os.rename(oldPath, newPath)
                count +=1

print('Renamed', count, 'files')

count = 0
#Give string to delete files which contain this string
removeThisFileNameIfContain = input('Enter string to delete files which contain this string: ')
while removeThisFileNameIfContain == '':
    print('Empty string not allowed')
    removeThisFileNameIfContain = input('Enter string to delete files which contain this string: ')

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for aFile in files:
        if '.py' in aFile:
            continue
        if removeThisFileNameIfContain in aFile:
            os.remove(os.path.join(subdir, aFile))
            count += 1
print('Deleted', count, 'files')
```

Work perfect when on local machine with python3, but when I uploaded into my VM, and executed remotely via cURL

I kept getting this

```
curl 45.55.88.57/code/fileModifier.py  | python3
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2266  100  2266    0     0  43381      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 43576
/Users/bheng/Desktop/projects/bheng/fileModifier
Remove this from folder names :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

What did I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage is taking up stdout, which the `input` command needs.

Try this if your shell has the ability:

```
python3 <(curl 45.55.88.57/code/fileModifier.py)
```

Note: As Amadan said, your syntax (and mine) run a remote script locally, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not executing the script remotely. You are fetching it then executing it *locally* by piping into Python REPL.

When you are piping the script into Python, `stdin` is where the program comes from. You cannot use `stdin` to also get data from `input()`.

To actually execute it remotely, you would need to either build in a web server in your code, or tell an existing web server to run your Python code (e.g. by registering a CGI handler).